# Second page (and next) of search results redirects me to the home page

Tags: search, server, configuration, nginx

WP 3.5, nginx (latest) and PHP5-FPM (latest).
If you visit http://bombacarta.com/?s=coma the page is properly loaded. When you click on the link to go to the next page, you are redirected to the home page. Try it out: http://bombacarta.com/page/2/?s=coma

I don't know what's the cause to this... I think it's something related to my nginx conf for WP (because it happens on also another installation on the same VPS with same config but different theme). Here's my nginx config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;           
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

location / {
# if you're just using wordpress and don't want extra rewrites
# then replace the word @rewrites with /index.php
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure there should be a second page of results? If there isn't page 2 would trigger a 404 which I'm guessing your config code is redirecting home.

Comment: Server-configuration topics are *off-topic*, as they are not **WordPress**-specific.

Comment: Looks like you fixed it. Care to share how?

Comment: It's not fixed.. look here too: http://luigisettembrini.gov.it/?s=scuola and http://luigisettembrini.gov.it/page/2/?s=scuola (there's a 2nd page for sure)..

Comment: Ok I found the problem. The search parameter isn't taken into account for /page/x/ structure. In fact http://bombacarta.com/page/2/ is the same of http://bombacarta.com/page/2/?s=coma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved changing the location block with this:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```